# Delete my own misguided question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

When I asked [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/39377/7532) I didn't understand enough basics to even formulate the question correctly.

Specifically, I asked about basis when the real question (as I now understand) was about how to depreciate something inherited in two separate blocks.  The question as written isn't really even meaningful, as this situation never results in having a single number you can call the "basis".  Each inherited block treated as a separate asset, and depreciates according to its own schedule starting when it was inherited.

Somebody provided an answer which is "correct" for the question as written, and which I accepted, but could give someone the idea that such a basis value is meaningful.  I.e. question was based on a flawed mental model, and that pretty much invalidates the question AND the answer.

I'm trying to decide what to do, and here are the options I see:

1. Ask a moderator to delete the question via a flag. I can't delete it because it has an upvoted answer.
2. Write my own answer explaining why it's a poor question, summarizing what I've since learned, and make it the accepted answer.

Both options penalize the person who provided a good-faith answer to the question as asked.

My question here: Which option would you recommend, or is there another way to improve the situation I haven't thought of?

Comment: Is providing an update on the post out of the question? State how you were misguided, how the answer is still correct but you wanted to elaborate anyway. You'll often encounter `Update:` blocks on the bottom of questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have any problems with the answer you've accepted, I wouldn't take any action. Both question and answer are upvoted; everybody's happy.

If you wish to edit the answer to add more details, that would be my recommendation.